# How to write a function to check if current time is inside time window

Tags: algorithm, go

I am trying to find a way to check if the current time is inside a time window.
The inputs are:
`upgradeDay []string` - a slice of days (for instance `["Sunday", "Tuesday"]`)
`upgradetime string` - hour:minute (for instance `"22:04"`)
`upgradeDuration int64` - amount of time, from the `upgradetime` at which the time window is valid. it can be up to 12 hours.
Full example:
`upgradeDay` = ["Sunday", Tuesday"] , `upgradetime` = "10:00", `upgradeDuration` = 2 -> the time windows is at every Sunday and Tuesday, from 10:00 to 12:00 o'clock.
I tried to write the following function, but it's not working in transition between days/months/years:

```golang
func isInsideTimeWindow(upgradeDay []string, upgradeTime string, upgradeDuration int64) bool {
    now := time.Now()

    ut := strings.Split(upgradeTime, ":")
    hour, _ := strconv.Atoi(ut[0])
    min, _ := strconv.Atoi(ut[1])

    // !! not working when now it's Monday 00:01 and got: upgradeDay = ["Sunday"], upgradeTime = 23:59, upgradeDuration = 2
    twStart := time.Date(now.Year(), now.Month(), now.Day(), hour, min, 0, 0, now.Location())
    twEnd := twStart.Add(time.Hour * time.Duration(upgradeDuration))


    if !(now.After(twStart) && now.Before(twEnd)) {
        return false
    }
    
    wd := now.Weekday().String()
    
    for i := range upgradeDay {
      if upgradeDay[i] == wd  {
         return true
      }
    }
    
    return false
}
```

Does someone got an idea on how to solve that in Go?

Comment: you could convert the times into Unix epoch time and then do numerical comparisons

Comment: or you can use `time.Since` for both dates and see if it's positive for one and  negative for another.

Comment: @Vorsprung can you elaborate?

Comment: @AlexYu can you also elaborate? Do you mean to `twStart` and `twEnd`? How does it solve that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of complexity in times.  For instance:

- What if an upgrade day is "Søndag" (Danish) instead of "Sunday"?
- Should we work in local time, or UTC?  If local, whose location counts?  If the server is in London and I am in San Francisco, do we use the server's time, or my time?
- If the upgrade interval includes 2 AM, does that count 2 AM PDT and then 2 AM PST as well?  These times are one hour apart where I live.  If the interval starts at 2 AM and ends at 2:59:59, that time does not exist on one day of the year in many areas with one hour DST shift.

If you get to ignore all these complexities—internationalization (i18n), localization (l10n), DST, and so on—there's still a bit of a problem with the fact that someone can set the date and time, or the upgrade itself might take some time, but usually we get to ignore these too.

Note that Go's `time.Now()` returns local time—but, whose location?  As we have not yet answered the *whose time zone to use* question yet, we might want to avoid worrying about this.  Given the rest of your input constraints, let's write a function to determine if a *supplied* time meets the input constraints, rather than if `time.Now()` does so.  The caller can then provide either a UTC time *or* a wall-clock time in the user's location:

```
someNow = time.Time()
localNow = someNow.In(location) // from time.LoadLocation() or similar
```

We also have something that seems at odds with your types:

> `upgradeDuration int64` - amount of time, from the upgradetime at which the time window is valid. it can be up to 12 hours

A value in hours that is between 0 and 12 inclusive fits easily in plain `int`.  Is this already a `time.Duration` value expressed in nanoseconds?  If so, why is it `int64` and not `time.Duration`?  Or is it a value in seconds, and therefore can be between 0 and 43200?  If so, it still fits in `int`.

I made a bunch of assumptions and came up with the following, which you can try out on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zCajy_gW4BS).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

// startOK determines whether the given starting-time is within a
// time window.
//
// The window starts at a time given as two integers,
// h and m, representing hours and minutes, and extends for
// the given duration d in hours, which in general should not
// extend into another day.  If it does extend past the end of
// the day into the next day, we ignore the extension.
//
// The days on which the time *is* in that window are further
// limited by the days[] slice of Weekday values.
//
// Note: it would probably be sensible to return a time.Duration
// value that is how long it will be until the next OK time, but
// we leave that as an exercise.
//
// It would also be sensible to allow the duration d to extend
// into the next day, which is also left as an exercise.
func startOK(when time.Time, days []time.Weekday, h, m, d int) bool {
    // Find OK-to-start time, and end-time.  If end exceeds
    // 24*60, we ignore the extra end time, rather than
    // allowing some minutes into the next day.
    start := h*60 + m
    end := start + d*60

    // Convert when to hour-and-minute and see if we are
    // in the allowed range.
    wh, wm, _ := when.Clock()
    now := wh*60 + wm
    if now < start || now >= end {
        // Not in hh:mm through hh+d:mm; say no.
        return false
    }

    // The time-of-day is OK; check the day-of-week.
    // We could do this earlier but by positioning it
    // here, we leave room to check to see if it's
    // the *next* day, if needed.
    if !func(wd time.Weekday) bool {
        for _, allowed := range days {
            if wd == allowed {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }(when.Weekday()) {
        return false // when.Weekday() not in days[]
    }

    // time is OK, day is OK
    return true
}

// startOKstr is like startOK but the window starts at a time
// given as a string encoded as hh:mm, with the days being a
// slice of strings instead of Weekday.  Because of these strings,
// parsing can produce an error, so this function has an error
// return.
func startOKStr(when time.Time, days []string, hhmm string, d int) (bool, error) {
    parts := strings.Split(hhmm, ":")
    // optional: be strict about two-digit values
    if len(parts) != 2 {
        return false, fmt.Errorf("invalid time string %q", hhmm)
    }
    h, err := strconv.Atoi(parts[0])
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    if h < 0 || h >= 60 {
        return false, fmt.Errorf("invalid hour value %s", parts[0])
    }
    m, err := strconv.Atoi(parts[1])
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    if m < 0 || m >= 60 {
        return false, fmt.Errorf("invalid minute value %s", parts[1])
    }
    var wd []time.Weekday
    for _, s := range days {
        w, err := parseWeekday(s)
        if err != nil {
            return false, err
        }
        wd = append(wd, w)
    }
    ok := startOK(when, wd, h, m, d)
    return ok, nil
}

// parseWeekday handles weekday strings.
//
// Ideally we'd use time.Parse for this, as it already has
// these in it, but they are not exported in usable form.
func parseWeekday(s string) (time.Weekday, error) {
    strToWeekday := map[string]time.Weekday{
        "Sunday":    time.Sunday,
        "Monday":    time.Monday,
        "Tuesday":   time.Tuesday,
        "Wednesday": time.Wednesday,
        "Thursday":  time.Thursday,
        "Friday":    time.Friday,
        "Saturday":  time.Saturday,
    }
    if v, ok := strToWeekday[s]; ok {
        return v, nil
    }
    return time.Sunday, fmt.Errorf("invalid day-of-week %q", s)
}

// tests should be converted to real tests and put in
// a separate file.
func tests() {
    okDays := []string{"Sunday", "Wednesday"}
    okStart := "04:00"
    okDuration := 2 // hours

    tfmt := "Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 2006"
    t1 := "Sat Sep 5 04:30:00 2020" // time OK, day not
    t2 := "Sun Sep 6 04:30:00 2020" // time OK, day OK
    check := func(s string, expect bool) {
        when, err := time.Parse(tfmt, s)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        result, err := startOKStr(when, okDays, okStart, okDuration)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        if result != expect {
            fmt.Printf("fail: expected %v for %q\n", expect, s)
        }
    }
    check(t1, false)
    check(t2, true)
    fmt.Println("2 tests run")
}

func main() {
    tests()
}
```

Comment: wow, thanks! I indeed got to ignore all the complexities, and had to use UTC time. I also had to allow the start + duration to extend into the next day, and made the exercise :-), I'll add this to here later.

Comment: ["Now returns the current local time,"](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Now) not UTC (unless the local timezone is set to UTC, obviously).

Comment: @Peter: Oh, right. I'm used to using servers on which local time is UTC.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach to the problem:

```
package main
import "time"
type window struct { time.Time }

func (w window) isDay(s string) bool {
   return w.Weekday().String() == s
}

func (w window) isHourRange(begin, end int) bool {
   return w.Hour() >= begin && w.Hour() <= end
}

func main() {
   w := window{
      time.Now(),
   }
   {
      b := w.isDay("Friday")
      println(b)
   }
   {
      b := w.isHourRange(20, 23)
      println(b)
   }
}
```

This assume only one day is valid, so you would need to modify this to handle
multiple days. This should get you started though.